# How to check the TEMPLATE_DEBUG flag in a django template?

Tags: python, django, templates

Do you know if it is possible to know in a django template if the TEMPLATE_DEBUG flag is set?

I would like to disable my google analytics script when I am running my django app on my development machine. Something like a {% if debug %} template tag would be perfect. Unfortunately, I didn't find something like that in the documentation.

For sure, I can add this flag to the context but I would like to know if there is a better way to do that.

Comment: Below answer are depreciated. Now with django you can make it much simpler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783459/how-to-check-debug-true-false-in-django-template-exactly-in-layout-html/25783860#25783860

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Assuming you haven't set `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` to some other value in `settings.py`, Django will automatically load the `debug` context preprocessor (as noted [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext)). This means that you will have access to a variable called `debug` in your templates *if* `settings.DEBUG` is true *and* your local machine's IP address (which can simply be 127.0.0.1) is set in the variable `settings.INTERNAL_IPS` (which is described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#internal-ips)). `settings.INTERNAL_IPS` is a tuple or list of IP addresses that Django should recognize as "internal".

Comment: It seems to correspond to my need but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I can't find what is wrong.

Comment: That works perfectly as long a I use a RequestContext rather than a Context. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oops, sorry! I did forget to mention that you have to pass a `RequestContext` to the template.

Comment: How do you check for it in the template?  According to the docs, ifequal is insufficient:

It is only possible to compare an argument to template variables or strings. You cannot check for equality with Python objects such as True or False. If you need to test if something is true or false, use the if tag instead.

However, {% if %} doesn't work.  It checks existence, not whether it's True or False.

Comment: The `if` tag *should* work. From the Django docs: "The `{% if %}` tag evaluates a variable, and if that variable is 'true' (i.e. exists, is not empty, and is not a false boolean value) the contents of the block are output."

Comment: Should be TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS, no?

Comment: @CarlG: Indeed. Updated.

Answer (score 59):

If modifying `INTERNAL_IPS` is not possible/suitable, you can do this with a context processor:

in `myapp/context_processors.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings

def debug(context):
  return {'DEBUG': settings.DEBUG}
```

in `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'myapp.context_processors.debug',
)
```

Then in my templates, simply:

```
 {% if DEBUG %} .header { background:#f00; } {% endif %}
```

Comment: I did not find any doc for this, and it didn't seem to be needed prior to django 1.6.. I find this a little old, any explanation ? Do I need to load any specific setting to the context ? This is not very conveniant I think..
Thanks for the tip though

Answer (score 30):

**Django 1.9+**

settings.py:

```
INTERNAL_IPS = (
    '127.0.0.1',
)
```

Templates:

```
{% if debug %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#internal-ips says:

> A list of IP addresses, as strings, that:
>
> - Allow the debug() context processor to add some variables to the template context.

The `debug` context processor is in the default `settings.py`.

Comment: @ÖzerS. the entire Django is arguably a hack! :-) (I think it's fine but I'm not 100%)

Comment: woking fine with django 2.1.8

Comment: Best solution so far

Answer (score 5):

If you haven't already, it always helps to see if/how others have dealt with same issue on djangosnippets. The most recent snippet working with analytics tag is 1656:
http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1656/

What is nice about this solution is that it allows you to keep your `GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_CODE = xxxxxx` in local_settings.py in the case rest of your source is public, your key remains private. In addition it goes an extra step to not use analytics for logged in users.

> Includes the Javascript for Google Analytics. Will not show Google Analytics code when DEBUG is on or to staff users.
>
> Use `{% googleanalyticsjs %}` in your templates.
>
> You must set something like
>
> ```
> GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_CODE = "UA-1234567-1"
> ```
>
> in your settings file.
>
> Assumes 'user' in your template variables is `request.user`, which it will be if you use:
>
> ```
> return render_to_response('template.html',{ }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
> ```
>
> (Assuming `django.core.context_processors.auth` is in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`, which it is by default)
>
> ---
>
> ```
> from django import template
> import settings
> register = template.Library()
>
>
> class ShowGoogleAnalyticsJS(template.Node):
>   def render(self, context):
>       code =  getattr(settings, "GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_CODE", False)
>       if not code:
>           return "<!-- Goggle Analytics not included because you haven't set the settings.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_CODE variable! -->"
>
>       if 'user' in context and context['user'] and context['user'].is_staff:
>           return "<!-- Goggle Analytics not included because you are a staff user! -->"
>
>       if settings.DEBUG:
>           return "<!-- Goggle Analytics not included because you are in Debug mode! -->"
>
>       return """
>       <script type="text/javascript">
>           var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
>           document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js'
>             type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
>       </script>
>       <script type="text/javascript">
>           try {
>           var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker('""" + str(code) + """');
>           pageTracker._trackPageview();
>       } catch(err) {}</script>
>       """
>
> def googleanalyticsjs(parser, token):
>   return ShowGoogleAnalyticsJS()
>
> show_common_data = register.tag(googleanalyticsjs)
> ```

Answer (score 5):

`{% if debug %}` can do the trick but only if you pass `RequestContext` instead of `Context`. Additionally, `debug` is not a boolean flag, its a function that when evaluated while `DEBUG = True` return some debugging information. This can be unnecessary overhead for your template.

Personally, I do this trick instead.

```
{% if request.META.HTTP_HOST == "127.0.0.1:8000" %}
```

This will always work but instead of relying on both DEBUG flag and INTERNAL_IP, it just work for the hard coded IP.

Comment: Better to move it to template tag with `takes_context=True` to not violate DRY.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the `DEBUG` flag to your `context_processors`.

There may not even be an alternative way. At least, none that I know of.