# How do I get a "debug" variable in my Django template context?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

According to this SO post:

[How to check the TEMPLATE_DEBUG flag in a django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271631/how-to-check-the-template-debug-flag-in-a-django-template)

if:

- A) my settings.py file has:

`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ['django.core.context_processors.debug',...`

- and B) I use a RequestContext (as opposed to a Context)

I *should* have a "debug" variable to my template context.  However, I don't: when I do `{{debug}}` in a template, it renders as nothing ("").

Is there anything else I'm missing that is necessary to get a "debug" var in the template context?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You also need to ensure the request's IP address is in the `INTERNAL_IPS` in your settings (which you probably don't have set): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-debug

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense.  I don't suppose you know of any way to bypass that requirement?  I work from multiple locations, and my development machine's IP address varies, so it would be nice if I could just say "if the debug setting is true, we're in debug mode; don't worry about my IP".

Comment: You could write your own context processor which just puts the `DEBUG` setting into the context.