# How do I use the debug variable in a django-cms template?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am new to django-cms and I cannot find the way of using the debug variable in a template. I basically want to do something like this

```
{% if settings.debug %}
     Development
{% else %}
     Production
{% endif %}
```

According to this question [How do I get a "debug" variable in my Django template context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020663/how-do-i-get-a-debug-variable-in-my-django-template-context), I should:

1. Add `'django.core.context_processors.debug'` to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`. I did this already.
2. Use a RequestContext (as opposed to a Context)

But how to do this without messing around in the django-cms files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you have to set your IP in the INTERNAL_IPS in your settings, see:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-debug