# how to check DEBUG true/false in django template - exactly in layout.html

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-settings

I would like distinguish a look of some toolbar in `layout.html` depending if DEBUG = True or not.

I am aware of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271631/how-to-check-the-template-debug-flag-in-a-django-template?answertab=active#tab-top) using `django.core.context_processors.debug` but it forces me to use `RequestContext` instead of `Request` what I not really like, btw how can I use RequestContext for `layout.html` which extends `base.html`?

And generally is there some better way to that than mentioned one or [the one using custom template tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271631/how-to-check-the-template-debug-flag-in-a-django-template/13609888#13609888)?

I am currently on Django 1.7

Comment: This is essentially the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271631/how-to-check-the-template-debug-flag-in-a-django-template/1271914, and the answer should probably be in that thread. (The answer to this question is also essentially the same as the accepted answer in the other thread.)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

In newer versions of Django it is possible just by specifying [`INTERNAL_IPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#internal-ips) in settings.

For example:

```
INTERNAL_IPS = (
    '127.0.0.1',
    '192.168.1.23',
)
```

and then in template just:

```
{% if debug %}
```

because context processors responsible for that by default, and the answers from [How to check the TEMPLATE_DEBUG flag in a django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271631/how-to-check-the-template-debug-flag-in-a-django-template) are bit deprecated.

Comment: JFTR, it also works in Django 1.8

Comment: it also works in Django 1.9

Comment: also works for Django 1.10

Comment: The list refers to client IPs, so `0.0.0.0` makes no sense.

Comment: @phk I updated the answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: It doesn't work for me

Comment: Confirmed for Django version 2.1.4

Comment: 2.2.2 confirmed

Comment: working fine with 2.1.8 and another server with 2.2.3

Comment: Note that the `debug()` context processor only returns true if DEBUG is set to true as well!

Comment: It also works for Django 4.0!