# Django include google analytics code only in production but not in development

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the google analytics code in a separate template, so I can just include it everywhere.

As i don't want the code to show in development, i'd just wrapped it in a `if` templatetag:

```
... header of any template
{% include 'analytics.html' %}
</head>
.... rest of page
```

Content of analytics.html:

```
{% if not debug %}
<script>
... analytics code
</script>
{% endif %}
```

**In development, it works as expected,** the analytics code is never shown.

**However, in production the analytics code only appears in the home page**, on every other page it keeps hidden.

Here is an extract of my urls.py (i'm using TemplateView):

```
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="landing/home.html"), name='home'),
url(r'^prices/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="landing/prices.html"), name='prices'),
url(r'^addons/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="landing/addons.html"), name='addons'),
```

Every of those templates has the  `{% include 'analytics.html' %}` on them, (i have not extended them from a common base as they vary too much in design).

and my template context processors:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",
)
```

I have `DEBUG` and `TEMPLATE_DEBUG` set to `False` in production.

I'm missing something?

Comment: Does this question & and its answer help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271631/how-to-check-the-template-debug-flag-in-a-django-template

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way to implement this would be to put your Google Analytics property id in your settings.py and write a custom context processor for it. You can include it in your base template (or in your case in every base template) like this:

```
{% if G_A_PROPERTY_ID %}{% include 'analytics.html' %}{% endif %}
```

And your custom context processor:

```
# context_procossor.py
def google_analytics(request):
    g_a_p_id = getattr(settings, 'G_A_PROPERTY_ID', False)
    if g_a_p_id:
        return {
            'G_A_PROPERTY_ID': g_a_p_id,
        }
    return {}
```

Don't forget to add your custom context_processor.py to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in your settings.py too.

On production server set G_A_PROPERTY_ID in settings.py file (or in local_settings.py if you use it), but not on development server. This way it should work as expected.