# Django DEBUG setting never evaluates as a boolean - only displays debug log

Tags: python, django, debugging

I have some GA code that we need to put on the live site only. So I'm trying to check the value of DEBUG, which in settings.py is being set to True currently. However, in my template file settings.DEBUG will not evaluate to either True or False. If I print out the variable, it displays the debug log.

I tried following this guide: [How to check the TEMPLATE_DEBUG flag in a django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271631/how-to-check-the-template-debug-flag-in-a-django-template) by adding the context_processors.py and still in my template file DEBUG comes out as the debug log.

template:

```
{% if DEBUG %}
<script>
    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
        i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
        a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
        a.async = 1;
        a.src = g;
        m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-xxx', 'auto');
   // ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
{% endif %}
```

settings.py:

```
DEBUG = True
...
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'appname.context_processors.debug',
)
```

context_processors.py:

```
from django.conf import settings

def debug(context):
  return {'DEBUG': settings.DEBUG}
```

Comment: You should show your code.

Comment: So, what does "comes out as the debug log" mean? The only place you are using DEBUG here is in the `if` statement, you are not outputting its value anywhere. (Plus, if you're using any recent version of Django, all the TEMPLATE_* settings are removed and have no effect. But that linked question didn't say to add your own context processor anyway).

Comment: That's when I print out {% DEBUG %}. I've taken it out for now. Are you saying it should be TEMPLATE_DEBUG? We've been successfully using just DEBUG in the rest of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things going on here.

Firstly, to output a variable you use `{{ }}` syntax not `{% %}`. The latter is for template tags. If you do `{% debug %}` you invoke the [debug template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#debug), which does indeed output a load of debugging information. To output your variable, you would do `{{ DEBUG }}`.

Secondly, settings such as TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS were deprecated several versions ago and have no effect. To add a context processor, you add it to the `context_processors` list in the OPTIONS dictionary of the TEMPLATES setting.

Thirdly, the question you linked to points out that you **do not need** to add your own context processor anyway, because one is already provided by default. `{{ debug }}` and `{% if debug %}` should work out of the box, as long as your IP is in the INTERNAL_IPS list.

Comment: We are already using ALLOWED_HOSTS. What's the difference between INTERNAL_IPS and that?